# Why flutter dynamic switch does not changing?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change switch, which are created dynamically by using future builder. it does not changing. Following is my script

```
bool disabledLanguage = false;
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
    var postId = snapshot.data[index].id;
    var postTranslate =  snapshot.data[index].translate;
    disabledLanguage = (postId == getLanguageId) ? true : false; 
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child:  _singleSwitch(postId, postTranslate, disabledLanguage),
    );
  }
)
```

and below is function in which I added switch functionality

```
_singleSwitch(postId, postTranslate, disabledLanguage){
    return  Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          postTranslate,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff41453c), 
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
          )
        ),
        Switch(
          value: disabledLanguage,
          onChanged: (value){
            setState(() {
              disabledLanguage=value;
            });
          },
          activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
        )
      ],
    );

  }
```

[image]

When I try to switch any language, it does not changing, i mean if english by default enabled, when I click on it, it should change to disable. It is not happening. Can someone please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to set postId value to getLanguageId instead of setting disabledLanguage.

Copy the below code to [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) and try. Go through the code once, You'll understand.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {

  var getLanguageId = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'translate': 'Eng',
      },
            {
        'id': 2,
        'translate': 'Kan',
      }
    ];

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Tutorial - googleflutter.com'),
        ),
        body: getListView(data)
    );
  }
  
  getListView(data) {
    return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var postId = data[index]['id'];
              var postTranslate = data[index]['translate'];
              var isdisabled = (postId == getLanguageId) ? true : false;
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: _singleSwitch(postId, postTranslate, isdisabled),
              );
            });
  }
  
  _singleSwitch(postId, postTranslate, isdisabled) {
    print('@Im here for' + postTranslate);
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text(postTranslate,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff41453c),
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
        Switch(
          value: isdisabled,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              getLanguageId = postId;
            });
          },
          activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```dart
setState(() {
  disabledLanguage=value;
});
```

`disabledLanguage` is a function argument. **You are updating a function argument and not an instance variable!**

1. Declare an instance variable `disabledLanguage`,
2. and remove `disabledLanguage` from parameter list so that the value is persisted after the function call.

It should look something like this:

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  ...
  ...

  bool disabledLanguage = true; //<-- Declared as instance variable

  _singleSwitch(postId, postTranslate){ //<-- Removed from parameter list
      return  Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            postTranslate,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff41453c), 
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
            )
          ),
          Switch(
            value: disabledLanguage,
            onChanged: (value){
              setState(() {
                disabledLanguage=value;
              });
            },
            activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
          )
        ],
      );

    }
}
```